# how can display data in three row instead 1 row?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

how can display data in three row instead 1 row ?
Each time I add a member a line that is added horizontally after 3 lines we move to another line,

i want something like this

name  name  name
toto  toto  toto
tata  tata  tata

I hope I have been clear.

**app.component.html**

```
    <!-- Table section -->
<section>
  <h2>Les membres d'équipages</h2>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let mydata of array[0]">
        <td>{{mydata.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  getUrl: string = 'http://localhost/get.php';
  postUrl: string = 'http://localhost/post.php';
  
  array = [];

  reactiveForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(),
  });

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMethod();
  }

  postMethod() {
    let myFormData = new FormData();
    myFormData.append('name', this.reactiveForm.value.name);

    return this.httpClient.post(this.postUrl, myFormData).subscribe(
      () => this.getMethod(),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }

  getMethod() {
    this.httpClient.get(this.getUrl).subscribe(data => {
      this.array.push(data);
    }, error => console.error(error));
  };

  onSubmit() {
    this.postMethod();
  };
}
```

[image: this is my table]

Comment: How does your table know you need to segment your data every three? You are trying to render a one-dimensional array as a two-dimensional array... Your `<tr>` rendering should be looping over groups of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no strong reason of using table, you can use div instead. With help of css you can place names in three columns.

**app.component.html**

```
<!-- Table section -->
<section>
    <h2>Les membres d'équipages</h2>
    <div class="three-column-wrapper">
        <div class="three-column header">Name</div>
        <div class="three-column header">Name</div>
        <div class="three-column header">Name</div>
        <div class="three-column" *ngFor="let mydata of array[0]">
            {{mydata.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**app.component.css**

```
.three-column {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%
}
.header {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

In case you are using bootstrap in your project you need to add classes of bootstrap there, and you html will be like\

```
<!-- Table section -->
<section>
    <h2>Les membres d'équipages</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">Name</div>
        <div class="col-4">Name</div>
        <div class="col-4">Name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4" *ngFor="let mydata of array[0]">
            {{mydata.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what you are trying to achieve it not clear and certainly not conventional but here are a few options

**Option 1**

```
 <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let mydata of array[0]">
        <td>{{mydata.name}}</td>
        <td>{{mydata.toto}}</td>
        <td>{{mydata.tata}}</td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
```

**Option 2**

```
 <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let mydata of array[0]">
         <td>{{mydata.name}}</td>
       </tr *ngIf="array[0].length % 3 == 0">
 </tbody>
```

Option 1 is certainly the correct way but if you need it the way option 2 can work.

One can also dynamically retrieve the columns and the rows from the dataset and use a combination of for loops and if statements to builds this  but that will be overhead.